# Instance of game crashes after I added background sound

Tags: c#

I started coding a simple game in Windows Form C#, but after I added the background sound (a simple .wav file) when I run the game, after a few second of playing the game crashes. (The sound can be heard). 
Here is the function:

```
private void playAmbientSound()
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer playAmbient = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.ambient);
    playAmbient.PlayLooping();
}
```

Then I call this function from the function **resetGame()** a function used in the Form constructor.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    resetGame();
}
```

The code that appears in the console after the crash is:

> .. has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access Violation'".

As requested here is the resetGame() function:

```
        private void resetGame()
        {
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            explosion.Visible = false;
            award.Visible = false;
            goLeft = false;
            goRight = false;
            score = 0;
            award.Image = Properties.Resources.bronze;

            roadSpeed = 12;
            trafficSpeed = 15;

            AI1.Top = carPosition.Next(200, 500) * -1;
            AI1.Left = carPosition.Next(5, 200);

            AI2.Top = carPosition.Next(200, 500) * -1;
            AI2.Left = carPosition.Next(245, 422);

            playAmbientSound();

            gameTimer.Start();
        }
```

Comment: What is the exception that is generated?

Comment: .. has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access Violation'.

Comment: @MitchWheat Do you have any suggestions on how to fix them? Or what might cause them?

Comment: In which class is your `playAmbientSound()`?

Comment: @MarkusZeller In the main class of the application (Form1)

Comment: Please show content of `resetGame()`. We need more information to debug or reproduce.

Comment: Try making playAmbient a property.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Make `System.Media.SoundPlayer playAmbient` a property of `Form1`.